# How can I subset data with matched observations?

Tags: r, select, dataset, subset

I have two data sets as below.

```
   ID     Var1 
   1      5
   2      7
   5      16


   ID     V1   V2
   1      1     5
   1      11    55
   1      55   12
   2      124   58
   2      58   99
   3       7   6
   3      44   88
   4      2     6
   4      4     99
   5      8      11
   5      58    12
```

I want to make a subset of below table that only contains IDs in the first table. In other words, I want to select observations from below table with ID = 1,2,5.
My raw data are much longer than posted ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `[`

```
dat2.subset <- dat2[dat2$ID %in% dat1$ID, ]
```

Using `subset`

```
dat2.subset <- subset(dat2, ID %in% dat1$ID)
```

Using join-like operations

```
merge(dat2, dat1, by = "ID")
plyr::join(dat2, dat1, type = "inner")
dplyr::inner_join(dat2, dat1)
```